# how to plot geom_col() to get y axis to center around 1 and not 0

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-col

I am plotting a some data using `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar`. The data represents a ratio that should center around `1` and not `0`.  This would allow me to highlight which categories go below or above this central ratio number. I've tried playing with `set_y_continuous()` and `ylim()`, neither of which allow me to sent a central axis value.

Basically: how to I make `Y` center around `1` and not `0`.

sorry if i am asking a question that's been answered... maybe I just don't know the right key words?

```
ggplot(data = plotdata) +
  geom_col(aes(x = stressclass, y= meanexpress, color = stressclass, fill = stressclass)) +
  labs(x = "Stress Response Category", y = "Average Response Normalized to Control") +
  facet_grid(exposure_cond ~ .)
```

As of now my plots look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "center around 1" since plotting a barplot means you'll fill space from 0 to whatever value it is you're plotting?
Maybe using `geom_point()` and limiting the y axis would be more suitable? you could have a single plot with a legend specifying your groups.

Comment: By "center around 1", I mean that, because a ratio of 1 means that bot the numerator and the denominator are equal, the plot should then use the value 1 as a base line and not the value zero. All values above a ratio of 1 are indicative of the experimental class being greater and all values less than 1 are indicative of the control being greater. Having the "center of the plot be 0 would illustrate this point more easily. Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-process your y-values so that the plot actually starts at 0, then change the scale labels to reflect the original values (demonstrating with a built-in dataset):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

cut.off = 500                                            # (= 1 in your use case)

diamonds %>%
  filter(clarity %in% c("SI1", "VS2")) %>%
  count(cut, clarity) %>%
  mutate(n = n - cut.off) %>%                            # subtract cut.off from y values
  ggplot(aes(x = cut, y = n, fill = cut)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n + cut.off,                     # label original values (optional)
                vjust = ifelse(n > 0, 0, 1))) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x + cut.off) + # add cut.off to label values
  facet_grid(clarity ~ .)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I guess it is easier to just modify the data, I thought there was some way of moving the y axis but this makes sense. Thanks, Z.